# Error in changing coding

Tags: java, encoding, coding-style

I have to change the site of coding from file (txt) to another one and I got an unexpected fail in that line:

out.write(line);

Here is the statement which I can notice : *Syntax error on token "line", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token*

And here is the whole code:

```
package snippet;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;


public class Snippet {

     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Michal/Desktop/1.txt");

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "iso8859-2");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(("C:/Users/Michal/Desktop/2.txt"));
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "utf-8");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(osw);

        String line = in.readLine();
        out.write(line);
}
```

Please tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Place your code in a method

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code inside main method to run. Also trows `IOException` at main method and close the `BufferedWriter` to save file data.

```
  public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String... arg) throws IOException{

      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Michal/Desktop/1.txt");
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "iso8859-2");
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(("C:/Users/Michal/Desktop/2.txt"));
      OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "utf-8");
      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(osw);
      String line = in.readLine();
      out.write(line);
      out.close();// Close BufferedWriter
   }
 }
```